# Issues 'unwrapping' an observable

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

On my authentication service I have the following:

**authService.ts**

```
user$: Observable<user>;

constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
   this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
            switchMap((userData) => {
                if (userData) {
                    // this.userID = userData.uid;
                    return this.db.doc<User>(this.PATH + userData.uid).valueChanges();
                } else {
                    return of (null);
                }
            })
        )
}
```

**page-component.ts**
And on another component I have my constructor like the following:
`constructor(public authService: AuthService) {}`

And on the html:
**page-component.html**

```
<div>{{ authService.user.firstName | async }}</div>
```

Shouldn't that 'unwrap' the Observable on the HTML? I get no errors but nothing shows up.
If I subscribe to the user on the *page-component.ts* and console.log, I do get the entire object.

Any tips?

Comment: Hey! That didn't work. It's in a different component right? The `user` doesn't exist on the `page-component` since it's a public reference observable from the `authService`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```html
<div *ngIf="(authService.user | async) as user"> {{user.firstName}}</div>
```

Because `authService.user` is the observable and you're trying to async `authService.user.firstName`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! What's the rational on this? I did try that but with out the ( ) . Thank you so much!

Comment: @iconio, the reason is as I mentioned earlier. 

Additional Information

If you have more than 1 observable say ```a$ b$ c$```

try 
```<div *ngIf="{a: a$ | async, b: b$|async, c: c$|async} as newVariable">{{newVariable.a}}
{{newVariable.b}}
{{newVariable.c}}
</div>```